# I'm currently trying to migrate a large table from cassandra to oraclesql and can't find many solutions

Tags: oracle, cassandra, data-migration

I've been researching and looking for ideas but the only thing close to a solution i've found has been where someone used pyspark to convert an oracle table into hdfs and then from hdfs into cassandra but I was hoping there was another/a clear solution to this data migration.

Answer (score 0):

Title suggests that it is Cassandra > Oracle. Message text says Oracle > HDFS > Cassandra (i.e. the opposite direction). What exactly are you trying to do?

---

Suppose it is the title that is correct. If there's no tool which would do the migration for you, from my - developer's - point of view, creating a database link in my Oracle schema which points to Cassandra might be a good option. Then I'd just write some SQL code to *migrate* data I need. Here's how: [Access Cassandra Data as a Remote Oracle Database](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-odbc-oracle-hs.rst).

Shortly:

- connect to Cassandra as an ODBC data source
- set connection properties for compatibility with Oracle
- configure the ODBC gateway, Oracle Net and Oracle database
- write queries

Comment: The database where the table is in is cassandra but im trying to migrate that data to oraclesql

Comment: That's what I'm talking about (actually, contents behind the link I posted).